# How to format codes automatically in ANTLRWorks?

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

is there any way to autoformat the codes I've written inside ANTLRWorks IDE?

Comment: What are you asking? "autoformat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option in ANTLRWorks.